# How to load new profile in Network manager v0.9 without nm-connection-editor using cli?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-networking, networkmanager

i'm working on migration of autoprovisioned Ubuntu 12.04 LTS servers from ifup (/etc/network/interfaces) to NetworkManager. /etc/network/interfaces is clean (only loopback interface is configured):

```
# cat /etc/network/interfaces 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

In this scenario, NM list one 'Wired connection 1':

```
# nmcli c list
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
Wired connection 1        e96b8486-3ea8-4f20-bd5a-2d532c2cf90a   802-3-ethernet    Wed 06 Aug 2014 03:13:29 PM CEST
```

/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ is empty:

```
# ls -la /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug  6 15:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Aug  6 11:37 ..
```

When i generate new profile and store it in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ i'm not able to persuade NM to register/load this profile:

```
# cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DHCP 
[802-3-ethernet]
duplex=full

[connection]
id=DHCP
uuid=25b9bcf8-1534-411d-8cb6-a3d4fcf33f5a
type=802-3-ethernet
timestamp=1407331036

[ipv6] 
method=auto

[ipv4] 
method=auto

# service network-manager restart
network-manager stop/waiting
network-manager start/running, process 1918


# nmcli c list
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
Wired connection 1        df785c8f-67e6-44c0-8434-2ca2b96d6408   802-3-ethernet    Wed 06 Aug 2014 03:27:16 PM CEST
```

I'm able to create new profile only using nm-connection-editor, but we can't use this method in autodeployments. Can anyone suggest, how to accomplish import and successful load of manually created NM profile into the NM?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use `/etc/network/interfaces` instead? In my humble opinion Network Manager is just extra complexity here.

Comment: definitely would! but it's an application team requirement, devs needs to edit network profiles and want to avoid parsing /etc/network/interfaces as it's not well parsable (nor want to use augeas for parsing and its ruby bindings) so trying to find a way how to use NM and its .ini style profiles... + need to allow app operators access to nm-connection-editor instead of manually editing the interfaces file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a way, how to succeed to import a NM profile with NM v0.9.4.0 installed  - **add-connection.py** example script in network-manager repo 
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/examples/python/dbus/add-connection.py

you only need to ensure 'python-dbus' (Debian/Ubuntu) or 'dbus-python' (RHEL clones) package is installed and everything work like a charm! :)